# Send a Spring Boot websocket message after connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

I need to send a websocket message to the user after the handshake, without waiting the user to send something.

I tried to use `afterHandshake` in a `HandshakeInterceptor`, however possibly the user is not identified yet.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    WebSocketConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/reply");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new UserHandshakeHandler())
                .addInterceptors(new MessagesHandshakeInterceptor(applicationContext));
    }
}
```

```
public record MessagesHandshakeInterceptor(
        ApplicationContext applicationContext) implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, 
                                   WebSocketHandler handler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response,
                               WebSocketHandler handler, Exception exception) {

        //send the message to the user
        applicationContext.getBean(SimpMessagingTemplate.class)
                .convertAndSendToUser(user, "/reply", message);

    }
}
```

```
public class UserHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {

    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler handler,
                                      Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        return () -> userId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?